# How to solve this NoMethodError in Home#index in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am storing some values in session this is what is my controller where i store values in session :

```
def callback
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new("ssssssssssss", "444444444444")
    if session[:atoken].nil?
      pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
      session[:atoken] = atoken
      session[:asecret] = asecret
    else
      client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
    end
    @loggedin_linkedin_userinfo = client.profile(:fields => [:id,:summary, :headline, :first_name, :last_name, :picture_url])
    @loggedin_linkedin_education = client.profile(:fields => [:educations])
    @loggedin_linkedin_position = client.profile(:fields => [:positions])
    @loggedin_linkedin_connections = client.connections

    session[:link_total] = @loggedin_linkedin_connections["total"]
    session[:link_headline] = @loggedin_linkedin_userinfo["headline"]
    session[:link_first_name] = @loggedin_linkedin_connections["first_name"]
    session[:link_last_name] = @loggedin_linkedin_connections["last_name"]
    session[:link_summary] = @loggedin_linkedin_connections["summary"]
    session[:picture_url] = @loggedin_linkedin_connections["picture_url"]

    redirect_to  :controller => 'home', :action => 'index'  
  end
```

this what is my view :

```
<div class="datainfo profile">
                        <h2 class="inner">Welcome, 
                            <% if session[:user].nil? 
                                session[:link_first_name] + " " + session[:link_last_name]
                            else
                                session[:user].first_name + " " + session[:user].last_name
                            end %>
                            </h2>
                        <p class="loc">
                            <%  
                            if session[:user].nil? 
                                Linkedinuser
                             else
                             @countryDetails = Country.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => session[:user].country_id})    
                            end
                                #for c in countryDetails
                                #c.country_name  #loop
                            %>
                            <% if session[:user].nil? 
                               Linkedinuser 
                             else
                                session[:user].city + "," + @countryDetails[0].country_name.to_s    
                            end
                            %>
                        </p>
                        <p class="job">

                        </p>
                        <p class="status">
                            <spam>
                                <% if session[:user].nil? 
                                        Linkedinuser
                                    else
                                        link_to "Complete Profile", session[:user], :class=>"small-btn" 
                                end
                            %>
                            </spam>
                            - Profile Completed %.
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

but when i run this i get the following error, Please help me.

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #35):

32:                     <div class="datainfo profile">
33:                         <h2 class="inner">Welcome, 
34:                             <% if session[:user].nil? 
35:                                 session[:link_first_name] + " " + session[:link_last_name]
36:                             else
37:                                 session[:user].first_name + " " + session[:user].last_name
38:                             end %>
```

I am struggling from morning but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `:link_first_name` key in your session (or it's `nil`) that's why it says `+` method is not defined for nils.

Check your session before doing that:

```
<% if session[:user].nil? && !session[:link_first_name].nil?
  session[:link_first_name] + " " + session[:link_last_name]
else ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. i get the following error now,undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass & the extracted source is <% if session[:link_first_name].nil? && !session[:link_last_name].nil?
35:         session[:link_first_name] + " " + session[:link_last_name]
36:        else
37:         session[:user].first_name + " " + session[:user].last_name
38:        end %>

Comment: would you please come for chat? it will help me Please

Comment: You also need to check whether the session[:user] is not `nil` in the else part

Comment: Still the problem continues, could you help me more?

Comment: You need to check your input (`session`) before doing any work with it, I could not write the code for you.

Comment: is the way i set session is correct? because i suspect that the values are not present in session.

Comment: i set values in controller but the view i call is not corresponding to that controller. ex: i set values in linkedin controller and call the home controller view. since i set values in session it must be accessible. this is what is my understanding. Please correct me if i am wrong.